# How to set text from listview Android-Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, listview, textview

I am making an album music application on Android Studio with ListView. now I want to make music notifications that are being played using textview. if the item in the listview is clicked, then the textview will change as written in the listview. can anyone help me? Here my code. Thanks for your attention. :)

```
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;

import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {


ListView songListView;
MediaPlayer player;


int[] IMAGES = {R.drawable.adzan_mp3_offline_1, R.drawable.adzan_mp3_offline_4};

String[] songs = {"song 1","song 2"};

int[] ids={R.raw.adzan_mp3_offline_turkey_a,R.raw.adzan_mp3_offline_turkey_b};


private AdView mAdview;
private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);



    songListView = findViewById(R.id.list);
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,songs);
    songListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    songListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);




}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

    if (player!=null && player.isPlaying())
        player.stop();

    player=MediaPlayer.create(this,ids[i]);
    player.start();



}

@Override
public void onBackPressed ()
{
    if (player != null)
        player.stop();
    super.onBackPressed();
}

@Override
public void onPause ()
{
    if (player != null)
    {
        player.pause();
        player.stop();
    }
    super.onPause();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

To get the text of the clicked listener use this

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
String currentText = parent.getItemAtPosition(position); // Assuming you've used only string
}
```

Another way to get the item clicked is to pass the position to Adapter and get the selected object from Adapter. Then you can use the selected object in any way you like.
Hope it helps